# How can i create excel sheet directly with datatable

Tags: asp.net, excel

I need all my data of datatable into a excel,but i don't want to use the for loop to write line by line.Because if the rows are 200 or more it is taking time.
IS there any fastest way to do it.

Comment: if 200 rows are already many for you.... I don't know what to say :) seriously, a for loop to export rows's values to a .csv file which you can open with excel is not a problem, do you already have the DataTable loaded in memory?

Comment: yes i am getting my data in a datatable(from a function runtime) then need to write that data to a sheet without using the for loop

Answer (score 0):

fastest way I know of is to got to the data tab: get external data, create a connection to the database using ODBC or whatever, and then select the table you want per sheet. it will run the a query and get all data based on the query or table specified.

You can then right click on the data section and refrehs the data anytime you want OR you can set the data to refresh on open, sheet activate etc.

This is a "PULL" approach as opposed to a PUSH approach others are discussing.